# Contradiction about this parameter in the C++ standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, this

I am learning about classes in C++. In particular, i came to know that `this` is a *prvalue* expression inside a non-static member function.

From [class.this#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.this#1):

> In the body of a non-static member function, the keyword this is a *prvalue expression* whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called...

But in the same document i came across [expr.call#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4):

> When a function is called, each parameter ([dcl.fct]) shall be initialized ([dcl.init], [class.copy], [class.ctor]) with its corresponding argument. **If the function is a non-static member function, the `this` parameter of the function** shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type conversion...

---

Now we know that if we have a function parameter named `var`, then the value category of that parameter `var`(as an expression) is an *lvalue*. Thus, reading the 2nd quoted statement above(that implies that a non-static member function has a `this` parameter), the same should apply to the `this` parameter. In particular, if `this` is indeed a parameter of a non-static member function then its value category(as an expression) should be *lvalue*.

This leads me to the conclusion that the standard contradicts itself in the context of the above 2 quoted statements because the 1st quoted statement says `this` is a *prvalue expression* while the 2nd quoted statement implies that `this` is an *lvalue expression*.

**My question is** that why this contradiction isn't removed from the standard by the standard committee since it follows quite naturally from the above two quoted statement. Also, is there a way to safely remove this contradiction.

PS: Note that in the above discussion, i said that *"the 2nd quoted statement implies that a non-static member function has a `this` parameter"* because if there is no `this` parameter then the statement *"If the function is a non-static member function, the `this` parameter of the function shall be initialized..."* given by the standard wouldn't make sense.

Comment: You can reconcile this apparent inconsistency by imagining there is an actual `this` parameter, which you cannot access directly because it is shadowed by the `this` keyword, which only gives prvalue access to the value of the `this` parameter, as if it were [`auto(this)`](https://wg21.link/p0849). Also, note that with <https://wg21.link/p0847>, we may one day get _actual_ `this` parameters, in a manner of speaking…

Comment: @user3840170 Wow, very interesting(that linked paper).

Comment: _the 2nd quoted statement implies that this is an lvalue expression_ I'd say gibberish implies nothing. _why this contradiction isn't removed from the standard by the standard committee_ Because nobody opened an editorial issue asking for this.